# convert php mcrypt_encrypt and decrypt to mysql function

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, hash, cryptography

I was encrypting and decrypting data using php `mcrypt_encrypt` and `mcrypt_decrypt()` with the following arguments:

- $cipher : `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256`
- $key : 32 bit hash sha1, generated as follow `substr(hash("sha1", $some_var),0,32)`
- $data : can be number or string
- $mode : `MCRYPT_MODE_CBC`
- $iv : 32 bit hash sha1 generated as follow `substr(hash("sha1", $other_var),0,32)`

Then the generated string is passed to `base64_encode` and the result is the encrypted data. 
The final function look something like:

```
function encrypt($data, $key1, $key2) {
    return
            trim( base64_encode( mcrypt_encrypt(
                    MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
                    substr($key1,0,32),
                    $data,
                    MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
                    substr($key2,0,32)
            )));
    }
```

i want to do the same thing using `mysql`, so i can decrypt data while selecting them. 
I want to write **mysql function** that encrypt my data the same as the php `encrypt` function above.

I searched mysql documentation and found that [`AES_ENCRYPT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt) can do the same thing as `mcrypt_encrypt` and  [`TO_BASE64(str)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_to-base64) can do the function of `base64_encode`

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `mcrypt_encrypt`(
    _data text,
    _key1 varchar(40),
    _key2 varchar(40)  
) RETURNS varchar(40) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
    DECLARE encryData varchar(40);        
    SET @@session.block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-cbc';
    SET encryData = AES_ENCRYPT(
        _data,
        SUBSTRING(key1,1,32),
        SUBSTRING(key2,1,32)
    );

RETURN TO_BASE64(encryData);

END
```

but it not working as the php function.

the output of `echo encrypt('abcdefg', $key1, $key2);` where

- `$key1` is '5c2787d529149d3016ce50451290df1779ec93c7'
- and `$key2` is '33db3475db4badb7f6ba86489257c873610e9298'
  is 'FO51NxIIdOO/UQYtCTGhf2O0eq52C0AnRNTr9CxdOZc='

while the output of

```
Select mcrypt_encrypt(
    'abcdefg',
    '5c2787d529149d3016ce50451290df1779ec93c7',
    '33db3475db4badb7f6ba86489257c873610e9298'
) as a
```

is 'FQ=='

i use:

- XAMPP for Linux 5.6.8-0!
- PHP Version 5.6.8
- MySQL 5.6.24 - Source distribution
- i disable case sensitivity in mysql

Comment: per the documentation `AES_ENCRYPT(str, key_str)` which is 2 parameters but per your code `AES_ENCRYPT(_data, SUBSTRING(key1,1,32),  SUBSTRING(key2,1,32) )` which is 3 parameters.

Comment: in the documentation `AES_ENCRYPT(str,key_str[,init_vector])` it can take a 3rd optional parameter if the encryption mod require one.

Comment: ok, they added that in 5.6 and I was looking at 5.5 documentation

Comment: When i wrote it as follow `SET @@session.block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-cbc';
Select 
TO_BASE64(AES_ENCRYPT(
  'abcdefg',
        SUBSTRING(key1,1,32),
        SUBSTRING(key2,'100'),1,32)
    )) ` it generate some thing like the correct one 'FdRajO8qwCU95uw2dUGomA=='

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differences Between Rijndael and AES](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748622/differences-between-rijndael-and-aes)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you created is that you are using RIJNDAEL in PHP, which is not the same as AES. AES is a subset of RIJNDAEL, which means that using RIJNDAEL may use parameters that are unavailable to AES - so an encryption with RIJNDAEL may not be decryptable when only using AES.

There is a question on StackOverflow detailing this: [Differences Between Rijndael and AES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748622/differences-between-rijndael-and-aes)

The key difference: AES always uses 128 bit blocks, and allows using 128, 192 and 256 bit length for the key (with an attack published suggesting that using a 128 bit key is the best security because longer keys may be weakened below 128 bit - IIRC it was in the area 112 bit, still enough, but you never know).

RIJNDAEL as offered by PHP specifies the BLOCK LENGTH - RIJNDAEL-256 uses 256 bits of block length, allowing for 128, 192 or 256 bits of key length. The only scheme compatible with AES is RIJNDAEL-128 with 128 bits of block length.

Two remarks about your other crypto options: I don't particularly like the idea that the key is the result of a hash function, because this reduces the amount of different characters to 16. An attacker, knowing that only 32 characters of hex have been used will truly welcome this info because it reduces the search effort tremendously. 32 bytes 0-255: 1.1E+77 combinations. 32 bytes of 16 chars: 1.2E+24. Using 62 lowercase, uppercase and digits: 2.2E+57 combinations.

Also the initialization vector should be purely random. The general usage is that the created IV is added to the front of the cipher result and split from there before decrypting. This is to prevent encrypting the same clear text to the same cipher text - randomness is simply the best choice you can make - anything else may weaken your cryptographic strength.

One more thing: You have to take care of padding the data you have to full blocks. There are several padding schemes available, starting with "pad with zero bytes", but the current recommended padding scheme seems to be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7

Comment: The attacks are mentioned on the Wikipedia page about AES. Specifically I was referring to this related-key-attack: https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/07/new_attack_on_a.html https://cryptolux.org/index.php/FAQ_on_the_attacks (the originally linked paper seems to be 404).

Comment: Is there any work around? Or any module that can do that  ?

Comment: When i run `echo mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);` it returns 32 but according to [ Differences Between Rijndael and AES][1] it should not be less than 128 maybe that is the problem. @Sven [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748622/differences-between-rijndael-and-aes

Comment: @AbdallaEssamAli Don't confuse different encodings and units. Mcrypt tells you the size in bytes whereas 128 is the block size in bits.