# PDI - How to implement rijndael CBC encryption in kettle?

Tags: kettle, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I have some csv's containing the sale transactions. The file is come from another department in another state and it's encrypted for security reason. It's encrypted using Rijndael-128 mode CBC encryption.

I need to decrypt the file before make a report about it. How do that using pentaho? I know pentaho provide GPG encrypt and decrypt steps but my requirement is use that Rijndael encryption.

Comment: Hi, If you can implement decrypt logic using java or javascript then you can load content of file in memory using "Load file content in memory" step and then apply decrypt logic on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the **user java class** step allows you to implement your own java code and decrypt the file from this step.

https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/User+Defined+Java+Class

Comment: how about Symmetric Cryptography step? Rijndael is like AES encrypt or not?

Comment: AES has a fixed block size of 128 bits and a key size of 128, 192, or 256 bits, whereas Rijndael can be specified with block and key sizes in any multiple of 32 bits, with a minimum of 128 bits and a maximum of 256 bits. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748622/differences-between-rijndael-and-aes#748645