# Rewriting RijndaelManaged decryption from C# to Python

Tags: c#, python, encryption

I'm looking into porting this "Decryption" function from C# to Python (Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10177020)

```
public static string Decrypt(string cipherText, string passPhrase)
        {
            // Get the complete stream of bytes that represent:
            // [32 bytes of Salt] + [32 bytes of IV] + [n bytes of CipherText]
            var cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
            // Get the saltbytes by extracting the first 32 bytes from the supplied cipherText bytes.
            var saltStringBytes = cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv.Take(Keysize / 8).ToArray();
            // Get the IV bytes by extracting the next 32 bytes from the supplied cipherText bytes.
            var ivStringBytes = cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv.Skip(Keysize / 8).Take(Keysize / 8).ToArray();
            // Get the actual cipher text bytes by removing the first 64 bytes from the cipherText string.
            var cipherTextBytes = cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv.Skip((Keysize / 8) * 2).Take(cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv.Length - ((Keysize / 8) * 2)).ToArray();

            using (var password = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passPhrase, saltStringBytes, DerivationIterations))
            {
                var keyBytes = password.GetBytes(Keysize / 8);
                using (var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
                {
                    symmetricKey.BlockSize = 256;
                    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                    symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                    using (var decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, ivStringBytes))
                    {
                        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes))
                        {
                            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                            {
                                var plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
                                var decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                                memoryStream.Close();
                                cryptoStream.Close();
                                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I have encrypted "Hello World" in C# and managed to get to the point where I have the correct values all the way to (and including) keyBytes in Python. I have tried to get the decrypted text using pprp (https://pypi.org/project/pprp/) and other libraries, but no matter what I try I only get "Wrong IV size" or junk data. I assume that I'm struggling with the PKCS7 padding, but at this point I'm just completely lost. Would highly appreciate any help on the last part. :)

```
import pprp
import base64
from pkcs7 import PKCS7Encoder      


cipherText = "JKjzaiOSreH+l0GSzsatS8nmohRisvINOwrEjHOwIqIXo88CQT0/al7V7vXOmuamfTeJ235O1SZ0Yd2BZk2e2V4MznT7hyzqzu5J326JIReXPeH6EdtPFrxhdTPsfb8Q"
passphrase = "a78356254f093b00e45434828110c7b5"

# This constant is used to determine the keysize of the encryption algorithm in bits.
# We divide this by 8 within the code below to get the equivalent number of bytes.
keysize = 256

# This constant determines the number of iterations for the password bytes generation function.
derivationIterations = 1000

# Get the complete stream of bytes that represent:
# [32 bytes of Salt] + [32 bytes of IV] + [n bytes of CipherText]
cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv = base64.b64decode(cipherText)
cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv=list(bytearray(cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv))

# Get the saltbytes by extracting the first 32 bytes from the supplied cipherText bytes.
saltStringBytes = cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv[:int(keysize / 8)]

# Get the IV bytes by extracting the next 32 bytes from the supplied cipherText bytes.
ivStringBytes = cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv[int(keysize / 8):int((keysize / 8) * 2)]

# Get the actual cipher text bytes by removing the first 64 bytes from the cipherText string.    
cipherTextBytes = cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv[int((keysize / 8) * 2):]

keyBytes = pprp.pbkdf2(passphrase.encode('utf-8'), bytes(saltStringBytes), int(keysize / 8))

print(base64.b64encode(keyBytes))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have made sense if you had posted the complete code, including the Rijndael-encryption (which you have implemented according to your description). Anyway, the existing Python code including the key generation using PBKDF2 generates the same data as the C# code.

[pprp](https://pypi.org/project/pprp/) implements only the Rijndael-[block cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher) itself. This allows only a single complete block to be encrypted. Both padding and [mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) are largely not implemented, i.e. they still have to be implemented by the user. The mode of operation defines how multiple blocks are encrypted based on a block cipher. "Largely" means that there is already an adapter that implements the (insecure) ECB-mode and PKCS7-padding. This does not help in this case, because the C#-code uses the **CBC**-mode and PKCS7-padding. For this the appropriate adapter must be implemented first. The existing implementation of the ECB-mode (adapters.py) can be used as a blueprint. A possible implementation (for the decryption) is:

```
import pprp
import base64

# CBC-Adapter
def rjindael_decrypt_gen_CBC(key, s, iv, block_size=pprp.config.DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE_B):
    r = pprp.crypto_3.rijndael(key, block_size=block_size) # for Python 2 use crypto_2 instead of crypto_3

    i = 0
    for block in s:

        decrypted = r.decrypt(block)
        decrypted = xor(decrypted, iv)  
        iv = block

        yield decrypted
        i += 1

def xor(block, iv):
    resultList = [ (a ^ b) for (a,b) in zip(block, iv) ]
    return bytes(resultList)

#
# Posted code goes here...
#

# Decryption
blocksize = 32
sg = pprp.data_source_gen(cipherTextBytes, blocksize)
dg = rjindael_decrypt_gen_CBC(keyBytes, sg, ivStringBytes, blocksize);
decrypted = pprp.decrypt_sink(dg, blocksize)
print("Decrypted data: " + str(decrypted))
```

With regard to the "Wrong IV size" error message, I suspect that the other implementations you tried are actually AES-implementations. AES is not identical to Rijndael, but a special [variant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/748645/9014097) of [Rijndael](http://web.archive.org/web/20070711123800/http://csrc.nist.gov/CryptoToolkit/aes/rijndael/Rijndael-ammended.pdf). For example, AES has a fixed blocksize of 16 Bytes, while Rijndael allows 16, 20, 24, 28 or 32 Bytes. In the C# code Rijndael with a blocksize of **32** Bytes is used, so that the IV, whose length must correspond to the blocksize, is also 32 Bytes large. If you use this IV in an AES-implementation, you will inevitably get an error message like "Wrong IV size" or something similar. In addition, pprp supports the blocksizes 16, 24 and 32 Bytes. By default a blocksize of 16 Bytes is used.