# Cannot match Rijdnael encryption between C# and Javascript / Node

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I need to convert an Rijndael encryption function from C# to Node. But I cannot match the result, even  with the same Key, IV, Mode and Block Size. What am I doing wrong?

C# MRE:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
byte[] encrypted;

using (Rijndael rijAlg = Rijndael.Create())
{
    rijAlg.Key = new byte[] {  63, 115,  38, 206,  45, 102, 229,  13,
    161, 196, 250, 133, 149,  70, 153,  33,
    218,  32, 135, 149, 150,  21, 143,  11,
    210, 115, 185, 163,  24,  70, 145, 141 };

    rijAlg.IV = new byte[] { 151, 121, 168, 83, 221, 99, 206, 230, 74, 190, 106, 212, 232, 117, 192, 37 };

    ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

    using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
            {
                swEncrypt.Write("1234");
            }
            encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(rijAlg.BlockSize); //128
    Console.WriteLine(rijAlg.Mode); //CBC
    Console.WriteLine(rijAlg.Padding); //PKCS7
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted)); //6d9SB6t9dktDJ+siSlFtOQ==
}
```

Node / Javascript MRE:

```
import Rijndael from "rijndael-js";

const key = Buffer.from([63, 115, 38, 206, 45, 102, 229, 13, 161, 196, 250, 133, 149, 70, 153, 33, 218, 32, 135, 149, 150, 21, 143, 11, 210, 115, 185, 163, 24, 70, 145, 141]);
const IV = Buffer.from([151, 121, 168, 83, 221, 99, 206, 230, 74, 190, 106, 212, 232, 117, 192, 37]);
const cipher = new Rijndael(key, "cbc");

const buffer = cipher.encrypt("1234", "128", IV);
console.log(Buffer.from(buffer).toString("base64")); //6ewzPyaxUgFX8IXW9iLJfw==
```

The result of encrypting `"1234"` in C# is `"6d9SB6t9dktDJ+siSlFtOQ=="` while in Node is `"6ewzPyaxUgFX8IXW9iLJfw=="`

Comment: The padding is different (PKCS#7 in the C# code, Zero padding in the NodeJS code). Why do you use this library and not the crypto module of NodeJS?

Comment: This was it. I switched to the Node crypto library and it works. Can you answer using the answer button so I can mark your comment as an answer?

Comment: Sure. I have put my comment as an answer.

Comment: Note that the code changed during the edit, which may have invalidated one answer by replacing 256 with 128. Please don't do that.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - The OP made the change long before both answers were posted. It is also the responder's duty to check whether the question has been changed and adjust their answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Both codes use different paddings: [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7) in the C# code and [Zero padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#Zero_padding) in the NodeJS code. This is the reason for the different ciphertexts.
In order for both codes to generate the same ciphertext, the same padding must be applied. Since PKCS#7 padding is more reliable than Zero padding, PKCS#7 padding should be used in both codes.

*rijndael-js* does not seem to support PKCS#7 padding, only Zero padding, s. [here](https://github.com/Snack-X/rijndael-js/blob/master/lib/rijndael-block.js#L50). Although PKCS#7 padding can easily be implemented by yourself, an alternative to the *rijndael-js* library is the built-in *crypto* module of NodeJS, which supports PKCS#7 padding by default.

Also note that *rijndael-js* implements the Rijndael algorithm, while in the C# code AES is used. This works because AES is a subset of Rijndael, s. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/748645/9014097). On the other hand, AES and not Rijndael is the standard, and since the C# side uses AES, it is obvious to use a *pure* AES implementation on the NodeJS side as well, which applies to the *crypto* module of NodeJS.

A possible implementation with the *crypto* module of NodeJS is:

```js
import crypto from 'crypto';
const key = Buffer.from([63, 115, 38, 206, 45, 102, 229, 13, 161, 196, 250, 133, 149, 70, 153, 33, 218, 32, 135, 149, 150, 21, 143, 11, 210, 115, 185, 163, 24, 70, 145, 141]);
const IV = Buffer.from([151, 121, 168, 83, 221, 99, 206, 230, 74, 190, 106, 212, 232, 117, 192, 37]);
const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, IV);
const ciphertext = Buffer.concat([cipher.update('1234', 'utf8'), cipher.final()]).toString('base64');
console.log(ciphertext); // 6d9SB6t9dktDJ+siSlFtOQ==
```

This implementation gives the same ciphertext as the C# code.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a bit tricky due to differences in how each environment handles encryption, especially with things like padding and block sizes.

In your C# code, you're using Rijndael with a block size of 128 bits (as indicated by rijAlg.BlockSize output), and the padding mode is PKCS7. This is pretty standard for Rijndael/AES encryption.

However, in your Node.js code, when you use rijndael-js and call cipher.encrypt, you're specifying "256" as the block size. This might be causing the mismatch. Rijndael supports various block sizes, but AES, which is a subset of Rijndael, is fixed at a block size of 128 bits.

So, a couple of things you might want to check:

- Block Size: Make sure you're using a consistent block size across
  both your C# and Node implementations. If you're aiming for AES
  compatibility, this should be 128 bits.
- Padding: Ensure that the padding scheme matches in both
  implementations. Mismatches in padding can lead to different results.
- Encoding: Check that you're handling text and byte encoding
  consistently in both environments. Sometimes, issues can arise due to
  differences in default character encoding.

Try aligning these parameters and see if that resolves the discrepancy. Encryption can be a bit finicky with these details, so it's all about making sure everything lines up perfectly.

Hope this helps and best of luck with your project!