# rijndael encryption getting BlockSize must be 128 in this implementation error

Tags: c#, encryption

I am working on an old project and i am stuck with an error in rijndael encryption. i cant use another encryption.
i am getting BlockSize must be 128 in this implementation error.
i have tried all possible solutions from stackoverflow but nothing worked

```
internal static string Encrypt(string plainText, string passPhrase)
{
    byte[] array = GetArrayMethod();
    byte[] array2 = GetArrayMethod();
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
    using Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passPhrase, array, 1000);
    byte[] bytes2 = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(32);
    using RijndaelManaged rijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged();
    rijndaelManaged.BlockSize = 256;
    rijndaelManaged.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    rijndaelManaged.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    using ICryptoTransform transform = rijndaelManaged.CreateEncryptor(bytes2, array2);
    using MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    using CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    cryptoStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
    byte[] inArray = array.Concat(array2).ToArray().Concat(memoryStream.ToArray())
        .ToArray();
    memoryStream.Close();
    cryptoStream.Close();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
}

internal static string Decrypt(string cipherText, string passPhrase)
{
    byte[] array = null;
    try
    {
        array = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    byte[] salt = array.Take(32).ToArray();
    byte[] rgbIV = array.Skip(32).Take(32).ToArray();
    byte[] array2 = array.Skip(64).Take(array.Length - 64).ToArray();
    using Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passPhrase, salt, 1000);
    byte[] bytes = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(32);
    using RijndaelManaged rijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged();
    rijndaelManaged.BlockSize = 256;
    rijndaelManaged.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    rijndaelManaged.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    using ICryptoTransform transform = rijndaelManaged.CreateDecryptor(bytes, rgbIV);
    using MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(array2);
    using CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    byte[] array3 = new byte[array2.Length];
    int count = cryptoStream.Read(array3, 0, array3.Length);
    memoryStream.Close();
    cryptoStream.Close();
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(array3, 0, count);
}

private static byte[] GetArrayMethod()
{
    byte[] array = new byte[32];
    using RNGCryptoServiceProvider rNGCryptoServiceProvider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    rNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes(array);
    return array;
}
```

expecting a solution on how i can solve this error

Comment: According to the documentation of the [`RijndaelManaged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged?view=net-8.0#remarks) class, it depends on the .NET version which block size is supported: In .NET Framework 128, 192 and 256 bits, in .NET only 128 bits.

Comment: If you need a blocksize of 256 bits on .NET, AFAIK this is not possible with native C# methods, but you need a third-party library such as BouncyCastle.

Comment: Note that Rijndael and AES are different algorithms, more precisely AES is a subset of Rijndael. Rijndael allows several blocksizes, while AES only allows 128 bits, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/748645/9014097) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to reply.  i migrated back to .netframework and everything worked