# Missing argument while converting RijndaelManaged in java

Tags: java, aes, rijndaelmanaged

while converting a .net code of decryption to java I got an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing argument
    at javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec.<init>(DashoA13*..)
    at com.motorola.gst.DecryptTest3.Decrypt(DecryptTest3.java:90)
    at com.motorola.gst.DecryptTest3.main(DecryptTest3.java:36)
```

well I'm trying it for the first time both decryption and converting a .net code to java

here is the .net code that I'm trying to convert

```
 private static string Decrypt(string encryptedText, string completeEncodedKey, int keySize)
        {
            RijndaelManaged aesEncryption = new RijndaelManaged();
            aesEncryption.KeySize = keySize;
            aesEncryption.BlockSize = 128;
            aesEncryption.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aesEncryption.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aesEncryption.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(completeEncodedKey)).Split(',')[0]);
            aesEncryption.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(completeEncodedKey)).Split(',')[1]);
            ICryptoTransform decrypto = aesEncryption.CreateDecryptor();
            byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64CharArray(encryptedText.ToCharArray(), 0, encryptedText.Length);
            return ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypto.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length));
        }
```

I went through many posts and found [Decrypting bytes encrypted by .NET's RijndaelManaged using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084923/decrypting-bytes-encrypted-by-nets-rijndaelmanaged-using-java) is more related to my case.

I followed these and wrote my decrypt function as ::

```
private static String Decrypt(String encryptedText, String completeEncodedKey,int keySize) {
        //get completeEncodedKey in bytes and then to string
        String decodedcompleteEncodedKey = StringUtils.newStringUtf8(Base64.decodeBase64(completeEncodedKey));
        System.out.println("Decoded completeEncodedKey Key ::  "+decodedcompleteEncodedKey);
        int indexComma = decodedcompleteEncodedKey.indexOf(',');
        System.out.println("COmma Index :: "+indexComma);
        String IV = decodedcompleteEncodedKey.substring(0, indexComma);
        String Key = decodedcompleteEncodedKey.substring(indexComma+1,decodedcompleteEncodedKey.length());
        System.out.println("IV::: "+IV);
        System.out.println("Key::: "+Key);


    byte[] sessionKey = null; 
    byte[] iv = null ; 
    byte[] plaintext = encryptedText.getBytes(); 
    Cipher cipher = null;
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(sessionKey, "AES"), new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        System.out.println("IllegalBlockSizeException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        System.out.println("BadPaddingException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        System.out.println("InvalidKeyException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        System.out.println("InvalidAlgorithmParameterException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.out.println("NoSuchAlgorithmException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        System.out.println("NoSuchPaddingException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

but now I'm getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing argument.

can anyone help me getting these errors fixed.
any help would be appreciated.
thanks!!

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?  If it is the `cipher.init(...)` line, then split it onto separate lines, so you can see exactly which of the three parameters is throwing.  It could be `cipher.init()` or it could be one of the two `new`'s that is throwing.  Break things out so you can localise the error more.

Comment: The culprit is new SecretKeySpec(sessionKey, "AES")..

Comment: it was because of byte[] sessionKey = null; but even if I'm putting byte[] sessionKey = Key.getBytes(); and byte[] iv = IV.getBytes() ; It is not solving my purpose... any idea where I'm missing

Comment: Please post complete stacktrace.

Comment: Wrong IV length: must be 16 bytes long at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.a(DashoA13*..)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineInit(DashoA13*..)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
 at com.motorola.gst.DecryptTest3.Decrypt(DecryptTest3.java:96)
 at com.motorola.gst.DecryptTest3.main(DecryptTest3.java:39)

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was calling `new SecretKeySpec(sessionKey, "AES")` with `sessionKey = null`.